# Get next set of data for jquery ajax autoscroll

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to set up a custom infinite scroll with jQuery and some Ajax. This is what I have so far:

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "posts/view/",
                    data: "",
                    success: function(results){
                        $(".container").after(results);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

It all works fine and dandy, but what I'm struggling to visualize is how to get the next "set" or, "page" of data. I'm using PHP and in my function I'll have something like getMore($page = 1). But how can I have jQuery keep track of what page it's currently on, and know which page is next? Should I set up some sort of increment function inside of jQuery so that it pulls the URL (e.g. posts/page/1/) and then simply add 1 to the url it passes via Ajax?

I feel like I'm really overthinking this, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a page counter inside the scroll closure:

```
(function(){

    //inner functions will be aware of this
    var currentPage = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "posts/view/" + currentPage,
             data: "",
             success: function(results){
                 $(".container").after(results);
             }
         })

         currentPage++;

         }

    });

})();​
```

And change your server script according to the `page` param you are passing.
If there is nothing more to retrieve, just answer with an empty body.

By the way, `POST` is not suitable for retreiving data, use `GET` instead.

Comment: Still trying to figure out if this is just me, but currentPage never seems to increment (but it does successfully retrieve the ajax data).

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to be called at all now that you have altered it. Do I have to specifically request the function now that you wrapped the whole thing?

Comment: @bswinnerton the wrapper is just to prevent the `currentPage` var to mess with the outer scope - just the anonymous wrapping function will know about it - you can just put such function's body inside your `$(function(){...})` as usual and you'll be done.

Comment: Got it! The increment should go before the after() function. You may want to just update this for future users. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I had a bug in the code. The final (and I'm sure it's working) version has the currentPage++ after the ajax call. That way there are no duplicate page requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can go for simpler way.
Put one hidden field like this

```
<input type hidden value="1" id="page" />
```

now before every ajax send take the pagevalue from that hidden field. And after every ajax success function increment the hidden fierld value like this.

```
$('#page').val(parseInt($('#page').val())+1)
```

Your ajax call will look like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "posts/view/"+$('#page').val(),
                data: "",
                success: function(results){
                    $('#page').val(parseInt($('#page').val())+1);
                    $(".container").after(results);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: How would I get the value of the hidden field to place into the Ajax call? text()?

Comment: Why inject this in the DOM when you can use a good ol' `int`?

Comment: in your code you have defined var currentpage inside scroll function.So everytime scroll happens your currentpage will goto 0. That is not what Op wants?

Comment: @AshirvadSingh thanks for pointing out, I wrote the right closure now.